# Scm Uri Error in Python function deployment from Bitbucket pipeline to Azure using microsoft/azure-functions-deploy:1.0.1

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, bitbucket

I have created a Bitbucket pipeline using the image python3.7.2 and I compressed the python function and pass to deployment as per the documentation in Bitbucket.But when I tried to deployed it using  - pipe: microsoft/azure-functions-deploy:1.0.1,It shows some error ValueError: Failed to retrieve Scm Uri

```
- step:
    name: build and test
    image: python:3.7.2
    script:
     - cat /etc/os-release
     - ls
     - apt-get update && apt-get install zip
     - zip -r sample-azure-python-func.zip ./*
    artifacts:
      - sample-azure-python-func.zip

- step:
    name: "deploy to dev function"
    deployment: Staging
    trigger: manual
    script:
      - pipe: microsoft/azure-functions-deploy:1.0.1
        variables:
          AZURE_APP_ID: $AZURE_APP_ID
          AZURE_PASSWORD: $AZURE_PASSWORD
          AZURE_TENANT_ID: $AZURE_TENANT_ID
          FUNCTION_APP_NAME: 'readfromip-sell-py-dev-fnap'
          ZIP_FILE: 'sample-azure-python-func.zip'
```

INFO: Deploying zip file
ERROR: Failed to retrieve Scm Uri
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/knack/cli.py", line 206, in invoke
    cmd_result = self.invocation.execute(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/**init**.py", line 328, in execute
    raise ex
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/**init**.py", line 386, in _run_jobs_serially
    results.append(self._run_job(expanded_arg, cmd_copy))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/**init**.py", line 379, in _run_job
    six.reraise(*sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/**init**.py", line 356, in _run_job
    result = cmd_copy(params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/**init**.py", line 171, in **call**
    return self.handler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/**init**.py", line 452, in default_command_handler
    return op(**command_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/appservice/custom.py", line 273, in enable_zip_deploy
    scm_url = _get_scm_url(cmd, resource_group_name, name, slot)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/appservice/custom.py", line 1374, in _get_scm_url
    raise ValueError('Failed to retrieve Scm Uri')
ValueError: Failed to retrieve Scm Uri